# How to make a 3D flip from a fragment to an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I am trying to make the flip transition to another activity on clicking a button in a fragment. I have set up onClickListener for the required button which calls another function, something like:

```
Button btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setOnClickListener(View.onClicListener(

@Override

public void onClick(View v)

{

fnTransition(v);

});
```

I tried opening an activity from a fragment using 2D animation defined in an xml file.

eg:

```
private void fnTransition(View v)

{

//some condition check

startActivity(getActivity(), intendedActivity.class));

getActivity.overridePendingTransition (R.layout.new_activity_animation, 

R.layout.leaving_activity_animation);

getActivity().finish();

}
```

Can a similar approach be employed to perform 3D animation transitions?

Comment: You wants omething like 3d in GoLauncher?

Comment: Something like the sample app provided in this link, although I guess they are switching between 2 fragments
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the 2 mentioned xml files with these nearly does the trick, although this is probably not the best way to do it.

xml 1 -> from_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromYScale="0.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

xml 2-> to_middle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

While this nearly does the trick, a better way would be preferable as it can be made out that this is not a proper flip.